# How to redirect page to another page in django for class based view?

Tags: django

I am new in django therefore i don't know how to redirect page to another page in django. Please help me to solve this issue.
This is my `urls.py` file

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^demo$', views.BookList.as_view(), name='demo'), 
)
```

This is my `views.py` file

```
class BookList(ListView):
    model = Book
    template_name = "demo.html"
```

here i am trying to redirect it to my `demo.html` file. I didn't get any error by this code but still page is not redirected.

Comment: Read the docs and complete tutorial ... and don't use class based views if you are newbie ...

Comment: You are using template_name with the wrong indent.

Answer (score 2):

To make a `view` redirect to another page, you have to specify a `url` where it should redirect.

You don't `"redirect"` to a template, you `"render"` a template. You can redirect to a url which renders a template.

To do a redirect in a view, you can use `RedirectView`. It will redirect to the given URL.

**Example:**

Suppose there is a view `MyView` which has a `url` defined in it. Then, whenever there is a `request` to `MyView`, it will redirect to the specified `url` .

```
class MyView(RedirectView):

    url = 'my_redirect_url'
```

You can also pass `url` directly in the `urls.py` like:

```
url(r'^my_view_url/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='my-redirect-url'))
```

In your above code, there was no error because `ListView` takes `template_name` as an attribute. It will then use this `template` to display the list of `Book` objects. Here there is no redirection happening, infact, the template `demo.html`  is being rendered which displays the list of `Book` objects.

```
class BookList(ListView):
    model = Book
    template_name = "demo.html"
```